# How do i store data in php after i generated the table dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

I want to take the attendance data as input which will be weekly attendance but the issue is I have to show the faculty/teacher who logged in only students who are assigned to the faculty/teacher so i inserted the data and retrieved using this logic. by using a while loop.

```
// Iterate over the fetched rows and populate the table dynamically
while ($row = $stmt_fetch_students->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['roll_number'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

the above code fetches the data from the 'student' table where in teacher column if the teacher is name is present the teacher will be assigned to the student and teacher can add the attendance for the student.

The image show the table from where the roll_number and name is being fetch for the while loop to create the table UI

[image]

This is the table UI through which i want to record the attendance data which is weekly data and store the data

[image]

i am clueless right now what to do and how will i store the data without having -> name="name" this sequence in input field

i don't know what are other method in php to store the data other than using the name constrint in the input field and storing the data. basically i want to store the data only for the student who are assigned to the teacher/faculty and that too using the subject are the mediator constaint where if the column name matches that of subject then the data will be stored along with the rollno.

Edit: Guys this is my first big project for college not a professional website for any institute. I am a beginner in php programming and i am right now in my 2nd year Computer Engineering Major.

Comment: Sometimes there will be two teachers with the same name

Comment: Do I see a `teacher` column with a comma seperated list of names in it? That is a very bad idea. Create a `teacher` table and link student to teachers with a cross reference table

Comment: I also see plain text passwords. That is *V.Very.Bad* practice. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: "The image show the table..."  Table info should not be stored in an image, please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Put the students' IDs into the field names - `name="attendance[26]"` for the "mark" user you got there, etc. Then you will get an array under the key `attendance` in $_GET/$_POST/$_REQUEST, and the second level keys will be your student IDs. So you can easily loop over those now, and update the records based on the ID, and the attendance value.